# Can't remove the event Listener, not understanding my mistake

Tags: javascript

I have a event listener which is assigned to a `div` using the `click` listener.

The problem is it does not remove the listener it just keeps adding to it.

This is the script where it is happening:

```
var resourceCheckout = function (quantity,btn){
    //quantity = integer
    // btn = document.getElementByID('the_div');

    var calculate = function (e) {
        var allowed = false;
        for(var i in test){
            var total = quantity * test[i].q;                        
            if(total > 200){ //if total > 200 remove eventListener
                allowed = false; break;
            } else {
                allowed = true;
            }
        };    
        if(allowed){
            btn.addEventListener('click',assign,false);
        } else {
            btn.removeEventListener('click', assign ,false);
        }
    };
    var assign = function (e) {
        do_it(quantity); //this gets called more than once when it should be
        // a maximum of one
    };
    calculate();
};
```

I decided to make a working ***jsfiddle*** to show you it in action, simply move the slider then hit the button, it will then call the function the listener is assigned to and count how many times it was called.

[***JSFIDDLE LINK***](http://jsfiddle.net/dexD2/9/)

I hope someone can explain my mistake as its getting confusing to understand as my script gets more complicated!

Comment: I can't immediately make out what your code is meant to be doing, but you're not using `removeEventListener` correctly. In your `resourceCheckout` function, you're creating an `assign` function -- a *different* `assign` function for every call to `resourceCheckout`. Then you (may) call `removeEventListener` with that newly-created `assign`. That won't do anything, because you've never added **that** `assign` to the button. (You may have added a **different** `assign` to it at some point.) The function you pass `removeEventListener` must be the **same** function you gave `addEventListener`.

Comment: You also only increment the total, you never decrement it.

Comment: @bwroga if the total goes up larger than increments of 1 then more than 1 listener was assigned. It won't go up if no assignment is assigned.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but with the slider it removes the listener but i used the same idea with that for resource which is why im confused.

Comment: *"I hope someone can explain my mistake as its getting confusing to understand as my script gets more complicated!"* One thing that can help there is consistent, rational code indentation. Your code is all over the place. Compare your fiddle with this version cleaned up by jsbeautifier.org: http://pastie.org/8144850

Comment: @Dave: *"but with the slider it removes the listener"* Because it's calling `removeEventListener` with the **same** function that was added via `addEventListener`. There's a big difference between that code and the `resourceCheckout` code: In the slider code, you're removing `endSlider` using a handler created by the same call to `initSlider` (the `startSlider` function). But this script is **dramatically** more complicated than it needs to be. I suggest stepping back, doing some further reading, and coming to the problem fresh.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so because i called the checkout from simplying doing `calculate()` it is not the same call? The reason it got this complicated is because i have to pass variables through to the functions that the event listeners are calling.

Comment: @Dave: *"so because i called the checkout from simplying doing calculate() it is not the same call?"* I'm sorry, I don't understand that sentence. Each call to `resourceCheckout` creates *new* versions of the functions created within it. In the code you've shown, the `calculate` function serves no purpose at all, the code in it may as well be in `resourceCheckout`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the function you try to remove has never been added, and so nothing is removed.

Every call to your `resourceCheckout` function creates a **new** `assign` function, which is then used by your `calculate` function. Since it's a **new** `assign` function, it cannot have ever been added to the button, so calling `removeEventListener` and passing it in has no effect.

If a previous call to `resourceCheckout` put an `assign` on a button, you have to use *that same function reference* to remove it.

This may be clearer with a simpler example:

```
function foo() {
    function bar() {
    }

    return bar;
}
```

`foo` creates a *new* `bar` function every time it's called. So:

```
var b1 = foo();
var b2 = foo();
console.log(b1 === b2); // false
```

`b1` and `b2` are *different* functions.

To make your `resourceCheckout` work, you'd need to remember the previous `assign` and use that to remove the handler.

You asked in a comment why this doesn't apply to the slider code in the fiddle, which looks like this (since it's not in the question):

```
// The OP's slider code
var initSlider = function (el,func,data) {
    var clickX = null;
    var startSlider = function (e) {
        clickX = e.pageX;
        document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', calc, false);
        document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', endSlider, false);
    };
    var endSlider = function (e) {
        document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', calc, false);
        document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', endSlider, false);
    };

    var calc = function (e) {
        var dif = e.pageX - clickX;
        clickX = e.pageX;
        var parentWidth = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el.parentNode).width);
        var childWidth = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).width);
        var childLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).left);
        var left = childLeft + dif;

        if (left < 0) { left = 0; }
        else if (left > (parentWidth-childWidth)) { left = (parentWidth-childWidth); }

        el.style.left = left + 'px';
        func(data,left,parentWidth-childWidth);
    };
    el.addEventListener("mousedown", startSlider, false);
};
```

There, the `startSlider` code successfully removes a handler from the `body` element. It works because the `startSlider` code has a reference to the `endSlider` function that was created at the same time `startSlider` was created (the same call to `initSlider`). So since `startSlider` has a reference to the same function that was used with `addEventListener`, `removeEventListener` works.

Comment: Okay i understand, where i get confused with is, with the slider you have to `mousedown` to activate the slider code. But with a button, it is dealt with from the `slider` changing values thus it needs to-recheck and either allow or block the user from using the submit button. Does that mean i should add the event listener in `initslider` for the button ? Then remove if needs be in the `checkout`

Comment: @Dave: I think you need to step back and approach the code completely fresh. Aside from some special cases, adding/removing handlers like this usually means you need to refactor. But fundamentally: If you want to remove the function later, you have to have a reference to the same function you passed into `addEventListener` so you can use that with `removeEventListener`. You can remember that reference in a variable or something.

Comment: @Dave: For instance: Why not just have a click handler on the button, and do the calculation when the click occurs and decide whether to `do_it()` or not?

Comment: Well that certainly is easier, but part of this is for me to learn about event listeners and how flexible it can get. I think that suggest is going to be smarter in long term though!! Most working examples never go this complex so i had to sort of guess :P

Comment: @Dave: In that case, remember a reference to the previous `assign` you hooked up, and use that to remove it.

Comment: Okay thanks for explaining all this! I started getting quite lost when i started doing more complex things with them.

Answer (score 0):

This code potentially adds a new listener for the event each time it is called.

Also note that every time you call `ResourceCheckout` a new different function object is created for variable `assign` and therefore the `removeEventListener` will never succeed because that specific function object passed has just been created and was never registered for the event (what was registered was a different function object, created in a previous call).